# Avocado substitute in blueberry muffin recipe

Tags: baking, muffins, avocados

I have a vegan blueberry muffin recipe.  I'm not vegan, but like anything as long as it tastes good.  The recipe calls for an avocado to be used as the fat.  I don't like avocado.  Is there something I can substitute for the avocado or should I just forgo this recipe?  I'm including the ingredients below:

- flesh from 1 ripe to very ripe medium/large Hass avocado, mashed very well (about 3/4 cup)
- 3/4 cups granulated sugar
- 1/3 cup canola or vegetable oil (melted coconut oil may be substituted)
- 1/3 cup Greek yogurt or sour cream (use vegan versions if desired)
- 1/4 cup light brown sugar, packed
- 2 teaspoons vanilla extract
- 3/4 teaspoon cinnamon
- 3/4 teaspoon nutmeg
- pinch salt, optional and to taste
- 1 cup all-purpose flour
- 1 tablespoon baking powder
- 1 1/2 cups frozen blueberries (keep them frozen, do not thaw them; fresh berries may be substituted and baking time may be a few minutes less)
- 2 tablespoons all-purpose flour, for tossing berries

Comment: Why do you assume the avocado flavor will stay prominent? Most fats lose most of their flavor in cooking (other than butter); this is why people can get away with putting mayonnaise in dessert recipes (not that I recommend it).

Comment: Mayonnaise is detectable in desserts when used.  You might not immediately recognize it for mayo, but it makes the dessert taste different or off.

Comment: @Brooke Do you know if you don't like avocado in baked goods though? Assuming you can still taste it, it won't have the same flavor that fresh avocado does, and it might not be a problem. But it's easy to replace too, I'm sure, so no big deal.

Comment: It depends on whether the complaint about avocado is more textural or more driven by aroma, but the texture in particular will likely not survive at all in a properly mixed recipe and the aroma would probably be substantially minimized. Mayonnaise may have additives like mustard for flavor, though foundationally the only flavor contributor unusual for a cake is vinegar (or lemon), which can mostly disappear thanks to chemical leavening and dilution.

Comment: I'm finding it incomprehensible that *anyone* is discussing substitutions here. There are a gazillion highly rated recipes for blueberry muffins that *don't* contain avocado. Why not look for one of those before messing with substitutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, when making muffin recipes, you can replace around 1/2 of the oil (sometimes up to 2/3) with applesauce or mashed banana without significant problems.  I don't know if you could get away with it in this particular case, as avocado would be a solid fat, so it might adversely affect the texture.

I'd personally try replacing the avocado with either mashed banana, coconut oil (mashed up some, but not melted), or a combination of the two.

Comment: Joe, that sounds like a great way to "fix" the avocado problem.  I love bananas and when mashed the textures are similar.  And banana  goes with nutmeg and cinnamon better than avocado might.  Adding a little coconut oil would also add some fat that the bananas might be lacking too.

Answer (score 2):

The recipe already has fat in it in the name of vegetable oil. It also has fat in the greek yogurt/sour cream. Increasing these will take the place of the avocado, how much is the question though. They don't give an amount of the avocado besides saying use one, and as they very in size you'd get a different result every time, and without an amount it's hard to say how much you'd want to add. Upping the oil and yogurt to 1/2 cup each would probably get you close.

Personally I'd just find a recipe without the avocado if you don't like it, there's loads out there so unless you have some sort of emotional attachment to it I'd chuck it and hunt for a better one.

Comment: I think you're right. I know better, but the picture and the person's commentary on the muffin make it look/sound really good.  But the avocado doesn't.  I think I'll stick to the recipes I already have and maybe modify them to add spices.

Comment: The fact that they don't say exactly how much avocado to use indicates that the exact amount isn't critical. If you replaced it with the "wrong" amount, it probably won't make a huge difference.